# How fo fix "Value Error" when using Mean Absolute Error in a RandomForestRegressor model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running a RandomTreeForest model with scikit learn library and when assessing its accuracy using `mean absolute` I get a ValueError:

> "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples".

The pandas dataframe I used comes from a real estate csv file that gets modified after I've added some missing values. Please see the code below.

```
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

X_train_plus = X_train.copy()
X_valid_plus = X_train.copy()

for col in cols_with_missing:
    X_train_plus[col + "_was_missing"] = X_train_plus[col].isnull()
    X_valid_plus[col + "_was_missing"] = X_valid_plus[col].isnull()

my_imputer = SimpleImputer()
imp_X_train_plus = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.fit_transform(X_train_plus))
imp_X_valid_plus = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.fit_transform(X_valid_plus))

imp_X_train_plus.columns = X_train_plus.columns
imp_X_valid_plus.columns = X_valid_plus.columns

model_1 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=50, random_state=0)
model_2 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
model_3 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, criterion="mae", random_state=0)
model_4 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, min_samples_split=20, random_state=0)
model_5 = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, max_depth=7, random_state=0)

models = [model_1, model_2, model_3, model_4, model_5]

def score_model (model, imp_X_train_plus, y_train, imp_X_valid_plus, y_valid):
    model.fit(imp_X_train_plus, y_train)
    pred = model.predict(imp_X_valid_plus)
    return mean_absolute_error(y_valid, pred)

for i in range(0, len(models)):
    mae = score_model (models[i], imp_X_train_plus, y_train, imp_X_valid_plus, y_valid)
    print("Model %d with extended imputed has a MAE: %d" %(i+1, mae))
```

I expect the output to be something similar to this:

> "Model 1 with extended imputed has a MAE: 345237"

But instead what I get is the following Value Error when return is calling mean_absolute_error within score_model function:

> "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2716, 10864]"

I think the mistake might be in the imp_X_train_plus and imp_X_valid_plus variables, however I have ran a very similar model that implements the dataframes and works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of your 3d line: `X_valid_plus = X_train.copy()`.

Did you mean to do: `X_valid_plus = X_valid.copy()`?